# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked In Unit Test and in-memory database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, testing, xunit

I'm testing a service that update something using xUnit and an in-memory database, but I'm getting this error when run the
UpdateContractPriceListGoodsItem_WhenEverythingIsOk_ShouldBeSucceeded and
this line want to excute

```
await _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository.Update(contractPriceListGoodsItem);
```

> The instance of entity type 'ContractPriceListGoodsItem' cannot be
> tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 2}' is
> already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that
> only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

during the update, Can someone explain the reason behind it and how I can resolve this issue?

this is my ContractServiceTests

```
public class ContractServiceTests
{
    private readonly IContractRepository _contractRepository;
    private readonly IPriceListOperationItemRepository _priceListOperationItemRepository;
    private readonly IPriceListGoodsItemRepository _priceListGoodsItemRepository;
    private readonly IContractPriceListGoodsItemRepository _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository;
    private readonly IContractPriceListOperationItemRepository _contractPriceListOperationItemRepository;
    private readonly IServiceOperationRepository _serviceOperationRepository;
    private readonly IFeatureGoodsRepository _featureGoodsRepository;
    private readonly IVisitProgramContractPriceListItemRepository _visitProgramContractPriceListItemRepository;
    private readonly IVisitProgramPriceListItemRepository _visitProgramPriceListItemRepository;
    private readonly IVisitRepository _visitRepository;
    private readonly PMOracleDbContext _dbContextOptions;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ContractServiceTests()
    {
        _dbContextOptions = new DbContextMocker().SetDbContext();
        _contractRepository = new ContractRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _priceListOperationItemRepository = new PriceListOperationItemRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _priceListGoodsItemRepository = new PriceListGoodsItemRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository = new ContractPriceListGoodsItemRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _contractPriceListOperationItemRepository = new ContractPriceListOperationItemRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _serviceOperationRepository = new ServiceOperationRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _featureGoodsRepository = new FeatureGoodsRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _visitProgramContractPriceListItemRepository = new VisitProgramContractPriceListItemRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _visitProgramPriceListItemRepository = new VisitProgramPriceListItemRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        _visitRepository = new VisitRepository(_dbContextOptions);
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new ContractAutoMapperConfiguration());
        });
        _mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(2,35000)]
    public async Task UpdateContractPriceListGoodsItem_WhenEverythingIsOk_ShouldBeSucceeded(long contractPriceListGoodsItemId,long price)
    {
        // Arrange
        var _contractService = new ContractService(
            _contractRepository ,
            _mapper,
            _priceListOperationItemRepository,
            _priceListGoodsItemRepository,
            _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository,
            _contractPriceListOperationItemRepository,
            _serviceOperationRepository,
            _featureGoodsRepository,
            _visitProgramContractPriceListItemRepository,
            _visitProgramPriceListItemRepository,
            _visitRepository);

        // Act
        await _contractService.UpdateContractPriceListGoodsItem(contractPriceListGoodsItemId, price);

        // Assert
        var result = _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == contractPriceListGoodsItemId);
        result.GoodsPrice.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(price);
    }
}
```

and this my service

```
public async Task<IdDto> UpdateContractPriceListGoodsItem(long contractPriceListGoodsItemId, decimal price)
{
    var contractPriceListGoodsItem = await _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository
        .GetContractPriceListGoodsItemById(contractPriceListGoodsItemId);
    if (contractPriceListGoodsItem is null)
        throw new NotFoundException(Resources.Resources.ContractPriceListItemNotFoundException);

    contractPriceListGoodsItem.GoodsPrice = price;
    await _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository.Update(contractPriceListGoodsItem);

    // Response
    return new IdDto { Id = contractPriceListGoodsItem.Id };
}
```

and this is my DbContextMocker

```
public class DbContextMocker : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly PMOracleDbContext _dbContext;
    public DbContextMocker()
    {

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PMOracleDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .Options;


        _dbContext = new PMOracleDbContext(options);

        _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();

        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }

    public PMOracleDbContext SetDbContext() { SeedDatabase.Initialize(_dbContext);
        return _dbContext;
    }
```

}

and this is my Update Code

```
public async Task Update(TEntity entity,CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    DbContext.Update(entity);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

and this is my seedr

```
   public class SeedDatabase
    {
        public static void Initialize(PMOracleDbContext context)
        {
            Seed(context);
        }

        private static void Seed(PMOracleDbContext context)
        {
            context.Contracts.AddRange(FakeListContract());


            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Contract> FakeListContract()
        {
            return new List<Contract>
            {
                new Contract
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Number = "20000",
                    Title = "First Test",
                    Price = 10000,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
                    IsActive = true,
                    ContractorId = 1,
                    ProgramType = ProgramType.ServiceProgram,
                    Description = "Test Description 1"
                },
                new Contract
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Number = "21000",
                    Title = "Second Test",
                    Price = 20000,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15),
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15),
                    IsActive = true,
                    ContractorId = 1,
                    ProgramType = ProgramType.VisitProgram,
                    Description = "Test Description 2"
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you read the actual error message? It says an object with the same key is already tracked.  There's very little EF code in the question but I suspect the CRUD classes with the ...Repository suffixes somehow end up trying to store the same objects multiple times. Putting a low-level CRUD class over a high lever Unit-of-Work like DbContext offers no benefits but it does make coding and debugging a lot harder.

Comment: A DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. A DbSet is already a single-entity Repository. They don't have CRUD methods because they don't need them. ORMs like NHibernate and EF Core give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not table rows. The don't need GetAll, Update or Insert. Putting a "repository" over the UoW probably *caused* the bug in the first place - when you call `Update` or `Insert` on a root object, all related objects are attached in Added or Modified mode but *not* stored.

Comment: If you try to `Insert` individual related objects as if you were inserting into tables, you'll end up trying to INSERT objects with the same IDs multiple times. I suspect the bug is inside `await _contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository.Update`. The very fact the method is asynchronous is a bug - DbContext.Update *attaches* an object in the `Modified` state, it doesn't save it. There's no reason for it to be asynchronous. That's not a bug. When SaveChangesAsync is called *all* pending changes will be saved in a single database transaction. If your `Update` is async, it's violating this process

Comment: And `_contractPriceListGoodsItemRepository.Update` is?

Comment: @GuruStron probably the same bug posted in almost all "repository" questions. An `Update` followed by a `SaveChanges`. Except in this case, the same DbContext instance is shared everywhere, causing each test to try to modify the same shared instance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos totally agree, but still the question should provide this info (IMO) =)

Comment: The immediate cause for the bug is probably all "repositories" are using the same DbContext and thus use the same tracked objects across tests. `DbContextMocker` doesn't mock anything, it returns a live DbContext object that's stored in the misnamed `_dbContextOptions` method. That makes it harder to realize that all repositories are using the same DbContext instance. All 11 parameters of the `ContractService` class are wrapping same shared object

Comment: but this error Happening when I just run this single test 'UpdateContractPriceListGoodsItem_WhenEverythingIsOk_ShouldBeSucceeded' in my ContractServiceTests @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: A test that fills the DbContext with data in `SeedDatabase.Initialize` (which is also missing) then tries to attach an object with an already existing ID. `Update` attaches the object in the `Modified` or `Added` state and will fail if a matching object is already loaded in memory. That's not a DbContext bug.

Comment: BTW that `Update` method completely breaks EF Core's concurrency model *and* can easily execute 42 DELETEs and 67 INSERTs. `SaveChanges` persists all pending changes, not just the latest one. It's meant to be called only once, at the end of a business transaction or controller action, to commit all changes at once. If you want to "roll back", you simply avoid calling `SaveChanges` and let the DbContext get disposed

Comment: BTW that's how you can fix the bug here - create the DbContext in each test in a `using` block. If you store it in a field, you're explicitly widening the "transaction" scope to the entire class

Comment: but why ef try to  attach an object with an already existing ID when i use the the update method nor add method? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Your code is doing that, not EF

Comment: BTW thank you I try to use the DbContext in `using` I hope this solve my problem

Comment: But when I run the application and call the service this update my data in the right way if my code have problem it  should throw an error not just in the unitTest @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You'd get the exact same error in production if you loaded the objects *before* calling `Update`.

Comment: I am Literally Confused when I need update something I get the object for example with the id then update the data then call Update method with the ef  is this a wrong method? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: We are all confused by this wall of code and the missing critical functions. You **don't need Update at all** if you load the entity from the database before modifying it. EF Core is already tracking it so it already knows it's modified. Simply calling `SaveChanges` would persist the changed properties. BUT if you used `AsNoTracking()` even though you intend to update, EF has no idea what changed. You need to reattach the detached property with Update all over again. And that will result in saving *all* properties, not just the changed ones

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by first caching your entity then re-attaching the entity via `Update()`. You should always check whether the entity is already attached before calling methods that throw when called with attached entities, such as `Update()`. The attachement of the entity seems to come from the database seeding. You should not use the same DbContext instance to seed your database and run your application / tests.

However, this is not how EF core is supposed to work. By default, your object is tracked by the change tracker. By changing the property, the entity is automatically marked dirty and you simply need to call SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync to persist the change to the database. This is more efficient than loading untracked or detaching the entity, as the change tracker will detect which properties are untouched and don't need to be sent to the DB in the UPDATE statement.

---

*Please note that EF core InMemory was designed to test EF core, not applications. You should either mock your repository or use your actual database driver instead of using the InMemory.*

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/

Comment: The OP claims this doesn't crash in production. I'd guess `Get` uses `AsNoTracking` so the bug wasn't discovered until now. It fails in the test because `SeedData` is adding objects to the DbContext itself, so even if `AsNoTracking` is used, the returned object is already being tracked

Comment: yes you are right in production I `Get` uses `AsNoTracking` but I wonder why  AsNoTracking  not work when ef Get the seed data from in-memory database @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You're asking me to guess the bugs in your code. Even though I'm doing pretty well, don't you think you should *remove* the bugs in the first place? Why are you using AsNoTracking if you fully intend to *track* ? Your code isn't working in production either. Just because it doesn't crash, doesn't mean it's not updating 20 fields instead of 1, or blocking other clients because you use `BeginTransaction` to reintroduce the lost transaction behavior

Comment: To answer your comment, the AsNoTracking() *does* work. The entity is already being tracked by the insert operation, and AsNoTracking is *not* expected detach the entity. I've updated my answer but you should still consider using the changetracker (and move away from InMemory).